# SlidingTabs with only 2 tabs

Tags: android, android-tabs

How can i do that with only 2 tabs and each tab view with 50% screen width? like the current Youtube apps. please help.﻿

The following screenshot (Left) is sample from android (right) is current Youtube app:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way it's modify source code of SlidingTabLayout.

To get current window size you could use this method:

```
public static Point getWindowSize(Activity ac) {
    Point size;
    Display display = ac.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getSize(size);
    return size;
}
```

Than in populateTabStrip method add layout params to

```
mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
```

method.

Smth like this

```
width = getWindowSize().x;
mTabStrip.addView(tabView, 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width/2, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: To make it more generic i added a `numberOfTabs` variable to the SlidingTabLayout, which holds the number of tabs you need. And then instead of dividing the width by 2, divide it by the variable. Obviously make a set method in the class and set it from your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding this method in your PagerAdapter (I assume you're using ViewPager): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getPageWidth%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect for me.

```
mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
```

from populateTabStrip() in SlidingTabLayout to

```
DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = display.widthPixels;
mTabStrip.addView(tabView, 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width/2, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

I guess there is no need to create method getWindowSize(Activity ac) as suggested in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone else needs this, I published the SlidingTab classes as a library and it has a method that solves this by calling `setDistributeEvenly(true);`. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

The library is at https://github.com/nispok/slidingtabs. To install it via Gradle just include:

```
compile 'com.nispok:slidingtabs:1.0.0'
```

Hope it helps!